# JVM argument to save heap dumps in different drive

Tags: java, jvm, jvm-arguments

I have my JRE on `C:` drive but I want my heapdumps to be saved on `D:` since I have less memory on `C:` drive. So I added the below JVM arguments

```
-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
-XX:HeapDumpPath=E:\SAVE\
```

After adding this arguments my tomcat didn't startup and failing with below error

```
Commons Daemon procrun stderr initialized
Please use CMSClassUnloadingEnabled in place of CMSPermGenSweepingEnabled in the future
Unrecognized VM option 'HeapDumpPath=E:\SAVE\'
```

After removing `-XX:HeapDumpPath=E:\SAVE\` tomcat starts up. Can someone please me whats wrong with the JVM argument?

Comment: It is Oracle's JDK 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the first option is `HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError`, which is slightly different than what you have:

```
-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
-XX:HeapDumpPath=E:\SAVE\
```

Comment: On the contrary, I believe that the quotes do matter, you shouldn't be using any; the options in a file such as this one are sucked in literally and passed as is as arguments to execve().

Comment: I stand corrected on the quotes.  I do think the other point I made though is valid.

Comment: Ah, oops, misread that; you are right about that one indeed; it is strange however that the JVM would fail on the path option, and not the previous one...